# In BLACKBERRY 9900 custom dialog font is not changing

Tags: java, blackberry

I am developing an application for blackberry 9900 where I am using custom buttons. But when I am using FontFamily fonts to change the font, its not getting affected. But when I run the same code in other simulators, the changes are getting affected. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are extending your class to Screen....Change it to MainScreen and remove super.This might change the screen's properties and solve your issue. Try it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the font you are used in your custom controls is not installed on a particular device. There's no `standard` RIM OS installation pack. Every mobile operator which has a contract with RIM may build his own RIM OS distribution pack. And in your case you get a device without this font installed.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case because when I go to setup, and change font there, it is affected. Even the font size also varies. By default it is taking BB Alpha Sans with size 8. But from development perspective its not a good option to tell the user to go to SETUP and change font or size manually. As a reason i want to change through program. It is specific to 9900 only

Comment: Try to run your application on different UI themes. Some UI themes may affect on font appearance.